# DiscordJS reactionCollector 'remove' is never emitted

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I want some code to execute when a reaction is removed, but the remove method isn't working. I set the dispose option to true, so I don't see why it doesn't work when I remove a reaction. Here is some sample code showing the bot.

```js
else if (msg.content.startsWith('!vote')) {
 //before collector
        var filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❌';
        let collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000, dispose:true});
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            //does some stuff that works
        });
        collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
            //doesn't get emitted   
        });
    });}
```

Comment: Looks like it's `collector.on('end'...` in the latest version. [Reaction Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector)

Comment: That's strange. I've just checked it and your code seems to be working fine, the [`remove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-remove) event is emitted as expected.