# DiscordJS V12 - reactionCollector 'remove' never emits

Tags: discord.js, event-listener

Similar to these questions:

- [How to use remove event with ReactionCollector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398000/how-to-use-remove-event-with-reactioncollector)
- [DiscordJS reactionCollector 'remove' is never emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770110/discordjs-reactioncollector-remove-is-never-emitted)

But none of the solutions listed in either solve my problem:

```
//Message filter and collector
const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['✅', '▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
}
//Create reaction collector
const reactionCollector = sent.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, { dispose: true, max: 1, time: 100000 });

//Message filter and collector
const messageFilter = m => m.member.id == this.player.id && m.content;
const messageCollector = sent.channel.createMessageCollector(messageFilter, { dispose: true, time: 100000 });

//Await message collector collect
messageCollector.on('collect', m => {
    //Emits fine
});

//Await reaction
reactionCollector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    //Emits fine
});
//Await remove
reactionCollector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
    //Never emits
});
//Await end
reactionCollector.on('end', r => {
   //Emits fine
});
```

No matter what I do, the remove event is never emitted.
I am using Discord.js V12.5.3

I have dispose: true and it still doesn't work

Comment: How do you know it doesn't emit ? Did you try putting `console.log('remove event fired')` on the event maybe just to be sure

Comment: I did -_- That's an obvious one. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

#### The collector ends on the first reaction

The collector ends on the first reaction because you set the `max` to `1`. For the `remove` event to be fired, the max must be 2 or above.

```js
sent.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, { dispose: true, max: 2, time: 100000 })
```

This can emit the `remove` event because the max is more than 1.

Comment: Tried this. It didn't work. I also removed the max variable and it still didn't work. Tested to make sure with console.log('remove emitted');